# Extending WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef

I've got a WPF MVVM application. One of my views has a user control that needs to be customizable for each installation. It's basically a sketch of the customers installation with some labels etc. bound to a viewmodel.

Now my problem is that this user control is different on each site/installation. One approach is to load the xaml from a file/database runtime using a xaml reader. This works but since my viewmodel is generic I have to bind to methods instead of properties and I can't load a xaml with `objectdataprovider`.

Currently I'm trying to see if MEF can be used so that I can create the user control as a plug-in. So what I'm looking for now is this:

1. how can I define a user control with view/view model that exports a contract for MEF
2. How can my parent view (in my wpf app) load the imported user control

Any tips are appreciated, or maybe someone has a different approach?

Comment: I don't understand this comment: "since my viewmodel is generic I have to bind to methods instead of properties."  What do you mean?

Comment: Lets say that one view has a binding to xCounter. a different view has a binding to xCounter and yCounter. these should rather bind to getCounter() with x and y as a parameter so that the viewmodel doesn't have to be changed just because of a new binding..

Comment: It sounds to me as though handling that difference should be the ViewModel's responsiblity, not the view's.  Perhaps you could post some sample Xaml & code to demonstrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you look into [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) in combination with MEF. It has a notion of Modules (plug-ins in your case) and Regions (mechanism of dynamically loading views).

You will be able to export a view using a simple attribute:

```
[ViewExport(RegionName = RegionNames.MyRegion)]
public partial class MyView : UserControl {
    public MyView() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Import]
    public MyViewModel ViewModel {
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }
}

[Export]
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
[
  ...
}
```

And in your main application XAML you will be able to import the plugin's views like this:

```
<ContentControl Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Infrastructure:RegionNames.MyRegion}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd consider is the design where you need to install a custom View for each installation.  Instead, I'd look to make that View more generic.  This will make your design more simple in the long run.  Plus, you are setting up for a maintenance nightmare with a different installation for *every* installed base.

It's a little difficult to tell from your description, but it sounds like the View is a collection of some kind of an object (some kind of drawing with a label or something).  Therefore, I'd treat it as such.

I'd create a base abstract class that describes what every object that your View could show.  Since I don't have more information, I'll call this thing a "DrawingObject" for lack of a better term.  This class would hold all information common to all objects in your View.  Note that ObservableItem is a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and SetProperty sets the value in that base class and raises PropertyChanged.

```
abstract class DrawingObject : ObservableItem
{
    Point mPosition;
    public Point Position
    {
        get { return mPosition; }
        set { SetProperty("Position", ref mPosition, value); }
    }

    String mLabelText;
    public String LabelText
    {
        get { return mLabelText; }
        set { SetProperty("LabelText", ref mLabelText, value); }
    }
}
```

Then, derive more custom objects from that base class:

```
class Counter : DrawingObject
{
    public Counter() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Your ViewModel would then just have a collection of these objects, using the base class.  The set may be private, because you will probably get the objects from someplace in the constructor (i.e. the database, or a flat file, or...)

```
class ViewModel : ObservableItem
{

    public ViewModel() : base()
    {
        // Call something to populate DrawingObjects property
        PopulateDrawingObjects();
    }

    ObservableCollection<DrawingObject> mDrawingObjects = 
        new ObservableCollection<DrawingObject>();
    public ObservableCollection<DrawingObject> DrawingObjects
    {
        get { return mDrawingObjects; }
        private set { mDrawingObjects = value; }
    }
}
```

Then, your View would bind to this collection and draw them appropriately (I'll leave that as an exercise for the implementer).

One extension that I didn't show is that the DrawingObject may need to implement the appropriate serialization functionality.

Obviously, this is a rough sketch of the design, and may have a couple of errors (I did it from my head), but hopefully it's enough to go on.